# How to use IN query in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

How do I run the `Where IN` query in Django ORM and iterate it? The following returns nothing:

```
user_ids = Wallet.objects.filter(customer_id=[sender_id,reciever_id])
print(user_ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`in`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup as

`user_ids = Wallet.objects.filter(customer_id__in=[sender_id,reciever_id])`